# SQL query deixando um dado da coluna personalizado

Tags: sql, query

Olá!

Gostaria de saber se é possível montar uma query que me retorne uma tabela semelhante a essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados da appB e appC vem de um select count na tabela Chamadas que me retorna a quantidade de sessoes encontradas por aplicação, porém os dados da appA vem de um select diferente pois tem regras de exceções. Nesse caso há alguma forma de unir os selects para que fique o resultado da tabela acima?

Obrigada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um union, por exemplo:

```
SELECT a.aplicacao, a.quantidade FROM tabelaA a
WHERE a.aplicacao = 'appA'
UNION
SELECT b.aplicacao, b.quantidade FROM tabelaB b
WHERE b.aplicacao = 'appB' OR b.aplicao = 'appC';
```

Lembrando, para o union funcionar as seleções devem ser do mesmo tipo de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se dessa forma pode ajudar:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT count(id) FROM appA WHERE condicoes) AS total_appA,
(SELECT count(id) FROM appB WHERE condicoes) AS total_appB,
(SELECT count(id) FROM appB WHERE condicoes) AS total_appC
```

Assim, você terá o resultado:

```
--------------------------------------
|total_appA | total_appB | total_appC|
--------------------------------------
| valor A   | valor B    | valor C   |
--------------------------------------
```